# Moving from function view to class based view

Tags: django, django-views

I have already running table with quite a lot of data. This table was designed years ago with not very clear assumption.
Table contains list of "services" we own. There is column 'service_id' which points to given entity. This entity has many instances. In fact, each month, we add new row (new instance), with new data but same 'service_id' for given entity.

Now, let's move to Django.
I use generic class based views, like ListView, CreateView, DetailView, etc. For this only specific case I need to use function view.
How to rewrite this function view to class based view?

VIEW:

```
def EsiDetailedView(request, requested_service_id):
    last_object=Esi.objects.filter(service_id=requested_service_id).aggregate(Max('id'))
    last_object_id=last_object.get("id__max")
    last_service=Esi.objects.get(id=last_object_id)

    args={}
    args['service'] = Esi.objects.filter(service_id=requested_service_id).order_by('-end_date')
    args['details'] = last_service #to show details of single service
    return render(request, 'esi/esi_details.html', args)
```

URLS:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:requested_service_id>/', EsiDetailedView, name='esi-detail')
    ]
```

Comment: What did you try and where did you fail
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#built-in-class-based-generic-views

Comment: Yes, this is helpfull. If i use eg. pk_url_kwarg to get the data I got last "pk" for given "service_id". I would need to also get all others (previous instances) with same "service_id". In short I would need to filter queryset with "service_id" which is put in the url.